# toggle class in wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, animation, toggle

Hello i am working on a wordpress site and trying to stop the below css animation on click (if a second click happens do nothing) in 2 elements on the menu of the site.

My HTML in the menu is

```
<div>

<div class="header-item bb-header-user-box bb-toggle pos-right">
    <a class="bb-header-icon logged-in-user element-toggle only-mobile" role="button" data-toggle=".bb-header-user-box .menu" href="http://www.website.com/profile/">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/35/5ea8283bc5098-bpfull.jpg" srcset="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/35/5ea8283bc5098-bpfull.jpg 2x" class="avatar avatar-150 photo" width="150" height="150"></a>
</div>

<a class="h-icon header-item create-post pos-right" href="http://www.website.com/create-article/"><span>Write article</span></a>

</div>
```

and there is css animation on classes

```
.create-post {animation: pulse-blue 2s infinite;} 
.bb-header-icon.logged-in-user.element-toggle.only-mobile img{animation: pulse-red 2s infinite;}
```

i dont want to remove the classes since they have more css rules in them. I just want to create a toogle with another class, for example

```
.stop-animation {animation-play-state: paused;}
```

that it can be triggered when user click on the elements and redirects page and stop the animation.

I tried to do something like that (for .create-post class for example) in the functions.php to add script in the head ->

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'stop_animation' );
function stop_animation(){
  ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".create-post").click(function(){
 // It should add class stop-animation to element
 $(".create-post").toggleClass('stop-animation',true);
  });
});
 </script>
   <?php
  }
```

but doesn't seem to work. I am not so good with js and jQuery and i am not sure what i am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Ps. Site is running default jQuery on it.

Answer (score 0):

Only use **toggleClass()**

```
 $(".create-post").toggleClass('stop-animation');
```

Comment: Thank  you for your answer but this didn't seem to work, add_action( 'wp_head', 'stop_animation' );
function stop_animation(){
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(".create-post").toggleClass('stop-animation');
</script>
<?php
}